# Imacros, web page to save to specific folder?

Tags: imacros

I have this macro for firefox, for web page saving (htm):

```
VERSION  BUILD=7500718 RECORDER=FX
'
'Ask for a name
!VAR1 NoName_Time_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}} 
'
'Save the page    
SAVEAS TYPE=CPL C:\Pages FILE={{!VAR1}}
```

It works OK, htm page is saved and images and css file are saved in created subfolder.
What I want to change is for jpg images and css files to be saved in specified folder such as ’C:\Images’ so that htm page can find them in that folder.
I tried:

```
SAVEAS TYPE=CPL FOLDER=C:\Pages FILE={{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}} TYPE=CPL FOLDER=C:\Images
```

But I got error: 
wrong format of SAVEAS command, line 5 (Error code: 910)

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
SAVEAS TYPE=CPL FOLDER=C:\Pages FILE={{!VAR1}}
```